# Need to return SINGLE column Date value in mybatis query

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis

I'm new to IBatis/Mybatis and ORM and Java in general.
I have a java mapper interface and the respective mapper xml. The domain object type that the query method should return is called SourceStatus. This object contains several attributes and getters/setters etc. I really only want to populate the date field of the SourceStatus domain object. Am I wiring my mybatis mapper file properly?

Java Mapper file containing method definition:

```
public interface SupportSourceStatusMapper extends TPBMapper {
    SourceStatus getSupportStatus();
}
```

MyBatis XML mapper file:

```
<mapper namespace="com.dealersInc.dao.mapper.SupportSourceStatusMapper">

<select id="getSupportStatus" resultType="Date">
    SELECT MAX(s_valid_frm_dat)
        FROM deals.supports_contracts
</select>

</mapper>
```

The SourceStatus domain object:

```
public class SourceStatus
{
    private long   contextKey;
    private String serviceName;
    private String contextName;
    private String contextRunType;
    private String contextLabel;
    private String contextStatus;
    private Date   cobDate;

getters/setters ()....
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

You could specify alias for SourceStatus, but for simplicity sake it's sufficient to specify fully qualified class name. Note that column name maps to SourceStatus property name:

```
<select id="getSupportStatus" resultType="com.dealersInc.domain.SourceStatus">
    SELECT MAX(s_valid_frm_dat) AS cobDate
        FROM deals.supports_contracts
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map result like this:

```
<resultMap id="StatusResult" type="com.dealersInc.domain.SourceStatus">

        <result property="cobDate" column="max_date" />

        <result property="optionalyOtherClassParams" column="other_column_name" />

</resultMap>

<select id="getSupportStatus" resultMap="StatusResult">
    SELECT MAX(s_valid_frm_dat) AS max_date
        FROM deals.supports_contracts
</select>
```

See http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps for more